# How to create a grouping variable from 2 variables in R

Tags: r, data-transformation, dataset

I want to reshape my dataframe to be able to group by two variables. Currently, my dataset looks like this:

[image]

And basically want it to look like this:

[image]

with gender being the grouping variable. Basically, what I want to do is to create a grouping variable for each observation in my date variable. All I seem to find from previous answers is handling the already grouped data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing between the "wide" and "long" data format. I do it using `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(df, idvars="Datum", measure.vars=c("male", "female"), 
    variable.var="gender")
```